# Converting KML to shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, kml, error-000800

I am trying to transform a kml to shapefile via ArcPy with the following code:

```
import arcpy

# Variables KML to Shapefile:
KML = r"C:\Test\Polygons.kml"
Output_Location = r"C:\Test"
Polygons_lyr = "Polygons_lyr"
Polygons_geo = r"C:\Test\Polygons_geo.shp"
Polygons_shape = r"C:\Test\Polygons.shp"
Polygons_gdb = Output_Location
Polygons_lyr = "Polygons_example" 
Polygon_select = Polygons_gdb

# Process: KML_To_Layer
arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(KML, Output_Location, Polygons_lyr, "NO_GROUNDOVERLAY")

# Process: Select_Data
arcpy.SelectData_management(Polygons_gdb, "Placemarks\\Polygons")

# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(Polygon_select, Polygons_geo, "")

# Process: Project
arcpy.Project_management(Polygons_geo, Polygons_shape, "PROJCS['WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_19S',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',10000000.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',-69.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "", "", "NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE", "")
```

When I run it, it performs the gdb and the layer:

[image]

But when (it seems) when selecting the file in the GDB, the problem occurs. It gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Test/KML_to_shapefile.py", line 17, in 
arcpy.SelectData_management(Polygons_gdb, "Placemarks\Polygons")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4310, in SelectData
raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of KML_to_shapefile.py | Polygons.kml | Polygons_example.gdb | Polygons_example.lyr.
Failed to execute (SelectData).

The error is in line 17, that is in the "arcpy.SelectData_management" function.

How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: What is arcpy.SelectData_management?  I do not see that as an arcpy tool.

Comment: What is it you're doing exactly? Why do you need to select the data that is created? The output creates a feature class you could simply project. Note, per the SelectData [help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-data.htm): `This tool is intended for use in ModelBuilder and not in Python scripting.`

Comment: There is a select data because I got the geoprocess directly from model builder (MB)(export script). But because of this, I realized that you can't always replicate an MB geoprocess to an arcpy script.

Answer (score 3):

From your code snippet, I think your task is to convert a KML and reproject it. You do not need to perform any sort of select. Your code can simply be the two geoprocessing tools:

```
# Process: KML_To_Layer
result = arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(KML, Output_Location, Polygons_lyr, "NO_GROUNDOVERLAY")

GDB_FC = result.getOutput(1) + "\\Placemarks\\Polygons"

# Process: Project
arcpy.Project_management(GDB_FC, Polygons_shape, "PROJCS['WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_19S',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',10000000.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',-69.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "", "", "NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE", "")
```

Note the tool, SelectData is a **ModelBuilder** tool. From the [help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-data.htm):

> This tool is intended for use in ModelBuilder and not in Python
> scripting.